# MAX9611/2 - receiving junk data

Tags: i2c, wire-library

I'm connecting to a MAX9611 on a custom PCB (using a SAMD Cortex M0 running an Adafruit Feather bootloader) using I2C. I have code that reads the voltage, current and temperature from the internal registers, but I'm receiving junk data from the voltage and current registers. Temperature works reliably.

Sometimes voltage and current are 0. Sometimes voltage is 10x what it should be (that's the raw ADC value - this isn't a conversion bug). The current reading depends on whether the temperature request is commented out or not.

I've been reading through the documentation for a day now and can't see what I'm doing wrong. The kicker is that the code to request the register data is essentially identical (just pointing at different registers) between the working temperature request and the non-working voltage and current requests. I have posted it below, along with the relevant schematic section - does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin();
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.print("mV:   ");  Serial.println(get_MAX9611_voltage());
  Serial.print("mA:   ");  Serial.println(get_MAX9611_current());
  Serial.print("Temp: ");  Serial.println(get_MAX9611_temp());
  Serial.println();
  delay(1000);
}

uint16_t get_MAX9611_voltage (void)
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x70);
  Wire.write(0x0A);                             //Select control register 1
  Wire.write(0x03);                             //Set mux to read from RS+
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x70);
  Wire.write(0x02);                             //Select RS+ data register MSB
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.requestFrom(0x70,2);
  uint8_t msb = Wire.read();                    //Read RS+ MSB
  uint8_t lsb = Wire.read();                    //Read RS+ LSB

  uint16_t MAX9611_voltage = word(msb,lsb);
  MAX9611_voltage = MAX9611_voltage >> 4;       //shift right by 4 due to 12 bit value
  MAX9611_voltage = MAX9611_voltage*14;       //57.3V full scale, 14mV per ADC step

  return MAX9611_voltage;
}

uint16_t get_MAX9611_current (void)
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x70);
  Wire.write(0x0A);                             //Select control register 1
  Wire.write(0x02);                             //Set mux to read from current sense amplifier with gain 8x, full scale = 55mV
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x70);
  Wire.write(0x00);                             //Select CSA data register MSB
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.requestFrom(0x70,2);
  uint8_t msb = Wire.read();                    //Read CSA MSB
  uint8_t lsb = Wire.read();                    //Read CSA LSB

  uint16_t MAX9611_current = word(msb,lsb);

  MAX9611_current = MAX9611_current >> 4;       //shift right by 4 due to 12 bit value
  MAX9611_current = (MAX9611_current*0.01342)*5;  //ADC value in millivolts, I=V/R where R is 0.2 

  return MAX9611_current; 
}

int16_t get_MAX9611_temp (void)
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x70);
  Wire.write(0x0A);                             //Select control register 1
  Wire.write(0x06);                             //Set mux to read from temp sensor
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x70);
  Wire.write(0x08);                             //Select temp data register MSB
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.requestFrom(0x70,2);
  uint8_t msb = Wire.read();                    //Read temp MSB
  uint8_t lsb = Wire.read();                    //Read temp LSB

  int16_t MAX9611_temp = word(msb,lsb);
  MAX9611_temp = (((MAX9611_temp >> 7) * 480)/1000);                     //shift right by 7 due to 9 bit value, LSB is 480mC

  return MAX9611_temp;
}
```

[image: MAX9611 schematic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That didn't take long to find the bug... Continuous read mode requires 2ms pause between each ADC read. I'm reading far faster than that, especially considering my micro is far faster than the 8 bit 328s that many other examples use. I added 2ms delay between reads and the problem seems to have disappeared, although I will have to check the current measurements when I have access to better equipment.

Comment: Happens to me too occasionally, that after writing a post searching for a bug for a long time, I find it myself shortly afterwards. Good that you posted the answer to help others with similar problems.